# Lua 3 point crossover help to start

Tags: lua, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I want to implement a 3 point crossover for genetic programming but I don't know how to do it and where to start.

My input is:

```
a = {(first pair), (second pair), ... etc.}
```

For example `a = {(12345,67890), (09876,54321)}`  (those are numbers, not strings)

Output: Something like this:

Example: `a_1 = {(12895), (67340)}` also numbers.

Thanks for reply and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my quick implementation of k-point crossover for integers using mostly integer arithmetic. Starting with this, you can extend it to crossover your chromosomes of many pairs of integers using a loop.

```
math.randomseed(111)
-- math.randomseed(os.time())

a = 12345
b = 67890
len = 5 -- number of digits

function split(mum, dad, len, base)
    local split = math.pow(base, math.random(len))
    local son = math.floor(dad / split) * split + mum % split
    local daughter = math.floor(mum / split) * split + dad % split
    return son, daughter
end

function kpoint(mum, dad, len, base, k)
    for i=1, k do
      mum, dad = split(mum, dad, len, base)
    end
    return mum, dad
end

s, d = kpoint(a, b, len, 10, 3) -- 3 point crossover in base 10
print(s) -- 67395
print(d) -- 12840

-- binary, (crossover binary representation)
s, d = kpoint(tonumber("10001", 2), tonumber("10110", 2), 5, 2, 3)
print(s) -- 23  which is (10111) in base 2
print(d) -- 16  which is (10000) in base 2


-- binary, (crossover base 10, but interpret as binary)
s, d = kpoint(1101, 1010, 4, 10, 3)
print(s) -- 1001
print(d) -- 1110
```

Comment: Should probably use `math.randomseed(os.time())` instead, otherwise it won't be random between runs.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Thanks, I wanted it to print what I say it prints. OP should be made aware in any case though.

Comment: Thanks, so if I change math.randomseed(111) to math,randomseed(os.time()), it will be random between turns?? Can I use it to swap binary numbers??

Comment: @rockethole see [MathLibraryTutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MathLibraryTutorial) for how to use `math.random()` properly (there are some snags). Lua doesn't have support for accessing the bit level representation of numbers. I updated the code with some examples for How you could go about using binary values in the crossover.

Comment: Thanks, the only problem that if i change use It for 16 bits and i change the lenght To 16. The result Will Be: 1.0110E^15

Comment: @rockethole Using the decimal (base 10) digits to represent binary will get outside the range 3-4 times faster than base 2. If you use the second approach (the one with base 2) you will not have this issue for 16 digits. You may find [printing binary values in Lua](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2002-10/msg00245.html) useful using base 2. If you need something even longer than 16 digits, then a string or table would be a more appropriate encoding instead of a number.